# Scraping xPaths in python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm making a webscraper in python. I want a line of code from a webpage that I have the xPath for. The xPath is `/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/svg/text[1]/tspan[4]`.

I can get to `div[2]` but not any further. My code is:

`one_a_tag = soup.findAll('div')[2]`

How do I get to the destination of my xPath?

Comment: Shouldn't you choose `soup.findAll('tspan'`) in that case?

Comment: Additionally, please share the website itself and code you have done so far to make us understand your problem clearly what you exactly try to get.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to locate items using xpath, then you will have to use lxml approach.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

URL = "Your page url here"
page = requests.get(URL)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

myItem = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/svg/text[1]/tspan[4]')
print(myItem)
print(myItem.text)
```